# Division of Cubes Among Children: Black and White Cubes Allocation Constraints

Tags: combinatorics

There are 13 cubes in total, with 5 white cubes and 8 black cubes. We want to determine the number of ways the cubes can be divided among 3 children, ensuring that each child receives at least 2 black cubes and no more than 3 white cubes.

For the black cubes, there are 6 possible cases. However, for the white cubes, I'm unsure about the accuracy as I tried to count all the cases

Comment: Can you likewise list out all possibilities? I don't think there are too many of them. EG $\{3, 1, 1, \}, \{3, 2, 0 \}, \ldots$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count all the possibilities when the possibilities are small.

If it gets out of hand, you can try this method to solve it.

Part 1: Division of black cubes

This is basically the number of solution to the equation,

$x_1 +x_2+x_3 = 8$

Since each child should be given atleast 2 cubes

$x_1 + 2+x_2+2+x_3+2 = 8$

$x_1 +x_2+x_3 = 2$

By combinations with repetition, number of solutions to equation

$x_1 +x_2+x_3 + ... +x_n = r$ is $\binom{n+r-1}{r}$

Plugging in the values we get

$4 \choose 2$ = $6$

Part 2: Division of white cubes

We first find the number of total solution to the equation and then remove the solutions where any child got more than 3 cubes

$x_1+x_2+x_3 = 5$

Following the same formula, we get

Total solutions = $7 \choose 5$ = $21$

Now we consider the case when one of the child get more than 3, that is atleast 4 cubes.

We can solve this the same way we solved the first part.
$x_1+x_2+x_3 = 1$

$3 \choose 1$ = $3$

But here, you can give at least 4 cubes to any child.
Hence total number of solutions in which any child gets more than 3 cubes is $3*3 = 9$

Total ways of distributing white cubes = $21-9$ = $12$

Hence total ways of distributing both the cubes is $6*12 = 72$